# MySQL syntax for LIMIT

Tags: php

I am using phpmyadmin version :5.5.20-log

I wrote a query:

```
 $query = "SELECT * ";
 $query .= "FROM `database`.`tables` ";
 $query .= "WHERE id=" . tabble_id ." ";
 $query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Each time I launch it using a web browser it throws an error report stating thus:

> database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1"

What syntax could be right for this?

Note: wrote this program using notepad++ text editor in php programing language!

Comment: What is in `tabble_id`?

Comment: tabble_id is a constant or  variable?

Comment: I think it should be $tabble_id

Comment: And it should be sanitized...

Comment: Since  $tabble_id or $table_id should be unique, how many rows do you expect to be returned, so that you have to limit the result to only one row????

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$tabble_id = value;`//define your value

```
 $query = "SELECT * ";
 $query .= "FROM `database`.`tables` ";
 $query .= "WHERE id=" . $tabble_id ." ";
 $query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

`tabble_id` should probably be `$tabble_id`

by just using `tabble_id` without the `$`, php probably sees it as an undefined constant, and smart-asses it to a string "`tabble_id`". You might be surpressing the thrown warning about this. The warning would be something like this:

`E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant tabble_id- assumed 'tabble_id' -- at line xxx`

You are ending up with this query , that off course is bad:

`SELECT * FROM`database`.`tables`WHERE id=tabble_id LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where id='' limit 0,1
```

Comment: I doesn't think this will make much difference

Answer (score 0):

Your tabble_id is missing $ symbol ,PHP variables should always start with $